# What should be the recommended PCB thickness for a circuit involving mains voltage, with 4 layers?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

The PCB manufacturer has asked if they can use thickness of 1.6mm, but my total stack-up thickness is 1.8mm.

This is the current stack up [image]

What additional considerations should I take into account to guarantee the safety and dependability of my circuit?

Specifically, if a thickness of 1.6mm is used (can save cost), could there be potential issues with electrical arcing?

It's important to note that the first two layers will carry the phase, is this bad design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What additional considerations should I take into account to guarantee
> the safety and dependability of my circuit?

It really depends on what IEC requirements the design will be subject to and what NRTL you will run the design through (like UL). Most of them follow IEC 61010 or IPC 2221 specs. It also depends on if mains means 120V or more. Even if you don't run your design through an NRTL, conforming to these requirements will prevent arching in most cases.

> Specifically, if a thickness of 1.6mm is used (can save cost), could
> there be potential issues with electrical arcing?

The IPC specs say you need 0.2mm on internal conductors at 100 to 300V so this means you would need to create space between any two conductors with these potentials (like mains hot or neutral and GND). One way to do this is to not run ground under the top or bottom layers and create a cutout, but it's up to you how this is done.
[image]
Source: https://resources.altium.com/p/using-an-ipc-2221-calculator-for-high-voltage-design

> It's important to note that the first two layers will carry the phase,
> is this bad design?

Not necessarily, but if you put the first two layers with a potential of 100 or more volts then this means you need 0.2mm of horizontal spacing, and you could not run signals over each other vertically on the PCB (which would violate spacing, because the first two layers are 0.071mm apart). If you want to provide adaquate spacing then they would need to be run on top and bottom layers or the internal layers. But L3 and Bottom layer would not work vertically same with L2 and Top Solder

Comment: If current is not too high, interior layers are safest for higher voltage to prevent problems with debris or moisture.  The spacing rules are for dry boards, so if you are running in a humid environment, be over-conservative.  Even if you have the high-voltage traces on the internal layers, keep the vias well-spaced.

Comment: I thought the 0.2 mm spacing was always about horizontal spacing, and vertical spacing you could rely on the board dielectric to withstand much higher voltages than air (or the relatively weak seams between layers). Fortunately, every high-voltage board I've done has been a two-layer 1.6 mm board, which is easily enough for the voltages they're used at, but that would be good to know in the future.